# C++11 member initializer lists

Tags: uncrustify

I am wondering if it is possible to configure uncrustify to format C++11 member initialization list. E.g:

```
bar::bar() :
    m_foo1{10},
    m_client_factory{
        ClientFactorySafePtr{
            new ClientFactory {10, 20, 30}}},
    m_foo2{20}
{
}
```

Uncrustify seems to think that m_client_factory initialization is a function, which is not good since it will cause incorrect formatting. Can this be done?